Generate a XML from a schematron
I have a use case of generating a correct xml so this can be published to my users as a sample payload.
I want to automate this process.
Unfortunately the only input I have is a schematron file. This schematron is something we do not own. It is a third party file.
But somehow is there a way to infer the xml from the schematron file?
One option I was thinking is to have one base template xml, tun through the schematron and depending upon the errors, add/update/remove new elements from the xml.
But the challenge there is inferring the meaning form the schematron is not reliable.
I don't know if there are any other approaches here.
Also I don't know if this problem is solvable.

Most projects I have seen that have a Schematron file to check business rules also come with an XSD 1.0 schema to define the grammar of XML instance documents. For XSD schemas there are tools in the .NET or Java world to infer a sample from a schema. So you might want to check whether your third party might as well have published an XSD schema file in addition to the Schematron file.

I've deleted the saxon tag from your question as it seems completely irrelevant.
Schematron is designed to enable you to define arbitrary predicates over your data, for example "every store in Portugal must be closed on Sundays".
I don't think there is any algorithmic way to generate data that conforms to such rules.
